# Built-in MATLAB command to find unknown upper limit that makes an integral equal to zero?

Tags: matlab, math

I need to know what command to use to find the upper limits (currently unknown) which return zero in the following integral. The lower limit is zero.

Integral: log(x)*sin(x)*cos(1/1+x^2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't mean to offer a tautology, but it sounds like you need to solve an integral equation.  Yours is an example of a Volterra equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation.  Knowing what to search for can be a leg up.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I just need to know how to use Matlab to find the potential values of the upper limit that make the integral equal to zero.

Comment: That's what solving a Volterra equation gives you.....

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49721-volterra-integral-equations-solver

Comment: Maybe I am being misunderstood. I don't have experience with Matlab. I don't know how to actually write a program in Matlab to give me a solution. I have been using the integral command to try and find some solutions using the IVT manually, I found one at 3.991. But I need a method that I can use in matlab which will do the hard work for me, to give me positive values that return zero.

Comment: I think parentheses are lacking  : you surely mean$\cos(1./(1+x.^2))$

Comment: @duffymo Pardon me, but I don't see the point of considering a Volterra equation here. The OP has here a numerical problem and there is a way to address it in a simple manner (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `fminbnd`, but for every starting point `x0` the solution will be different, depending on the area starting point resides in:

```
f1=@(x)log(x).*sin(x).*cos(1/(1+x.^2)); % f 
f2=@(x)integral(f1,eps,x); % integral of f, from epsilon to x
f3=@(x)abs(f2(x)); % minimum at 0
max_x_range=20; max_n_trials=200;
figure(1);clf;fplot(f3,[0.1,max_x_range]);
x_found=0;
n=0;
while n<max_n_trials
    n=n+1;
    x0=x_found+(max_x_range-x_found)*rand; %random x0 larger then founc
    x=fminbnd(f3,x0,max_x_range);
    if f3(x)<0.01
        if x>x_found
            x_found=x;
        end
        hold on; plot(x,f2(x),'*');
        disp([x,f3(x)])
    end
end
```

If you want to find the global minimum you need to try different starting points untill you find a solution that actually give you zero.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer. However, is this finding the upper limit value that makes the integral of the equation stated equal to zero?

Comment: I fixed it. Now it search for the integral.

Comment: See the remark I just made to the OP about parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, **Newton's method** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method
(one of the most efficient root finding method) is directly usable in the following way :

```
clear all;close all;hold on;
f=@(x)log(x).*sin(x).*cos(1./(1+x.^2)); % parentheses added in cos() !
F=@(x)integral(f,0,x); % antiderivative of f such that F(0)=0.
%x=0:0.01:5;plot(x,f(x));plot(x,arrayfun(@(x)F(x),x),'r') % see figure.
x0=4;x=x0; % starting point ; different x0 may not give the same limit...
for k=1:5; % 5 steps are usually sufficient
   x=x-F(x)/f(x); % Newton's iteration
end
x
F(x), % should be almost 0
```

[image]

Fig. 1 : f  in blue and F in red. Roots materialized as black circles.

One finds that

- with starting point x0 = 1.5, the result is x = 1.6466 with F(x) = -3.2446e-10.
- with starting point x0 = 4, the result is x = 4.2133 with F(x) = -3.2448e-10.
- with starting point x0 = 8, the result is x = 8.0445 with F(x) = -3.2447e-10.

etc. "ad libitum" : due to larger and larger fluctuations around the x-axis, there will be an infinity of solutions.

Remark :

Strictly speaking, f is undefined for x = 0 but taking f(0)=0 is a natural choice (even for Matlab !) because f(x) can be written under the form

```
                   f(x) = (x log(x)). (sin(x)/x) . (cos(1/(1+x^2))
```

When x tends to 0, on the RHS, the first parenthesis tends to $0$, the second tends to 1, and the third tends to cos(1). Thus their product tends to 0.